# Why doesn't my software detect DX11?

Tags: video, graphics-card

I recently purchased a Geforce GT 430 video card, which I'm sure has DX11 support. When I run Aliens vs. Predator, and I try to set the DX11 features, it tells me that I DX11 hardware is not found. I'm running Windows XP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out this [list of DirectX releases](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/DirectX) from Wikipedia. It was never released for Windows XP and is only available on Windows 7 and Windows Vista with Service Pack 1 or later. Even though your card supports it, your OS does not. Maybe it's time to upgrade?

**Also:** DirectX 10 isn't available on XP either; 9.0c was the last XP compatible release.